# Guide book of SNAP

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing, copernicus

I would like to study SNAP Software made by ESA. I don't find any PDF or book online. Have you any ideas where I can find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, there is no specific book to learn how to use the program. You can always learn with the official documintation (https://step.esa.int/main/doc/) & the official tutorials : http://step.esa.int/main/doc/tutorials/

Answer (score -1):

Snap help should be accessible from within the application. Selected tutorials are available [online](http://step.esa.int/main/doc/tutorials/). Not sure if a SNAP guide book exists, your Google skills are as good as mine...